# Creating my own observable with rxjs and angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two components on the same page. The first one displays a list of item while the second one is a refiner for the displayed items. I'd like to use `Observables` in a service in order to establish a "communication" between the two components.

So, in my mind, it would be something like:

- The first component subscribes to the observable and, in the same time, retrieves the unfiltered list of items.
- When the user clicks a refining criteria in the second component, a service function is called to emit something on the `Observable` and therefore, the first component receives a new list of item and update its view.

It seems simple but I can't wrap my head around the different classes (`Subscription`, `Subscriber`, `Subject` and `Observable`). The closest I've been was by using `Subject` but I have no idea how to send the initial list of items when there is a new subscriber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. If you want every subscriber to get the previously emitted values, use a [ReplaySubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md). This will replay the whole list (or whatever buffer length you chose) to every new subscriber.

If you have a fixed start value for the ReplaySubject, use a [BehaviorSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md).

You want to use one of those two as a private property within your service. When you call the service with a new list, call `.next` on the Subject. Add a public getter method for the Subject where you convert it to an Observable (with the `.asObservable()` method). This is used for subscribers to get the values. (You don't want to make the Subject itself public to prevent others from changing it.)

A Subject is an Observable and an Observer at the same time, which means you can not only get values from it (via the Observable interface), but also add those values yourself (via the Observer interface).

Comment: It seems to work thanks. Now I just have to find a way to initialize correctly the items with a test call and my service will be finished. Thanks for your help ;-)